# WebGL: Using a JS Blob with BufferData

Tags: javascript, websocket, webgl

I have a Blob object (received via a binary websocket) that I would like to upload to the GPU using `gl.BufferData()`. Just passing the Blob object to `gl.BufferData()` gives the error

```
WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: bufferData: size == 0
```

The size of the Blob is not 0. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself, the trick is to use a FileReader object:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, reader.result, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
}
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(data);
```

Comment: The real trick would be to use [`socket.binaryType = "arraybuffer"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)

Comment: You're right. Do you expect a big performance different between using Blobs (as above) and using arrayBuffers directly? In my case, I don't care about the type of the data, just want to move it to the GPU as quickly as possible.

Comment: tbh except for File up-/downloads I don't see a reason why one would want to use the `Blob` interface. Using `FileReader` will certainly have some kind of performance penalty over directly specifying the `binaryType` on the socket. Afaik a `Blob` is stored on disk while an `ArrayBuffer` always resides in memory.